# SQL convert datetime to day name

Tags: sql

I want to convert from datetime to day name but I have problem failed convert.

Edit: convert from date column to day name

Database sql

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Code used:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, date) AS date , name, date 
FROM kkpsurabaya
```

Comment: What data type is the date column? What database are you using?

Comment: Please post what database you are using and the table structure of the kkpsurabaya table.

Comment: did u see the labble? "sql convert datetime to day name"

Comment: You aren't going to get much help with that kind of response. You are being asked which database software (SQL Server, MySQL, etc) you are using - Also what datatype your field `date` is. Don't be rude to those trying to help you.

Comment: SQL is a generic term that means *Structured Query Language*. It is used by many DBMSs that have different syntax and different functionality. I don't see any **table** in your post, because you've not provided one. You've also not told us what database you're using or provided any information about the data types. Rather than taking an attitude, [edit] your question and provide the details you've been asked to provide. If you want help, give us the information we need to have in order to help. If you don't want to do that, ask your question at another site.

Answer (score 0):

solved by me: i convert varchar from insert to datetime and work.